# Use Ajax to populate the content of popover of Twiterbootstrap

Tags: jquery

How can I access an object's data elements individually in Jquery?

For example this is my object:

```
myobj=

Object 
        0:Object {id: "123", firstName: "John", lastName: "Brown"}
```

Im pretty new to Jquery I want something like myobj[0][1] which is firstAame.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accesss it using the named key `firstName`.

looks like `myobj` is an array, so the first item can be access using the index `[0]` which is an object, so the property `firstName` can be accessed as given below

```
myobj[0].firstName
```

Comment: Thats great I appreciate it :_

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate your array using `each` function
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/
http://api.jquery.com/each/